# C#: Make instance of the subclass

Tags: c#, generics

I have a base class like

```
abstract class A <TEntity, TLog>
{
    public abstract TLog Get(TEntity entity);
}
```

and few subclasses like

```
class B : A<Branch, BranchLog>
{
    public override BranchLog Get(Branch entity)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

now can i get the instance of the a subclass depending on its generic implementation of the base class like,

```
class Mapper
{
    public TLog GetMapped<TEntity, TLog>(TEntity entity)
    {

        /*if called with GetMapped<Branch, BranchLog>, make instance of B b = new B()*/
        /*returng b.Get(entity)*/
        return null;
    }
}
```

or any way rather than reflection

Comment: without reflection? using `as` and `is` ?

Comment: @Dipon: what is it that you are actually trying to do here? How will the clients of the Mapper-class actually use your Mapper-class?

Comment: The most efficient way is with reflection.

Comment: but reflection would force to load the hole assembly first. Which is little bit of concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add one more generic parameter which tells the type. Constraint the new generic parameter with `new()` so that we can new it up and `A<TEntity, TLog>` to make sure only instances of `A` or its subclasses can be passed.

```
class Mapper
{
    public TLog GetMapped<TType, TEntity, TLog>(TEntity entity) where TType : A<TEntity, TLog>, new()
    {
        TType instance = new TType();
        return instance.Get(entity);
    }
}
```

Then call it as

```
Mapper mapper = new Mapper();
mapper.GetMapped<B, Branch, BranchLog>(branch);
```

Comment: I wish there was a way to call just `GetMapped<TType>` and let compiler infer `TEntity` and `TLog`... I had a dream kind of thought.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Yes, it always frustrates me that compiler can't do that. I think they didn't implemented this feature because you can implement multiple generic interfaces. So there will be a ambiguity in inferring. For abstract classes they could have.

Comment: They could still implement it in a way which lets you do it when there is one possible resolution and throw and error when it's ambiguous.

Comment: No, this is not something a compiler will be able to infer for you.  Why? Because it has no clue which types of A<,> will be around at runtime, even when you are only using abstract classes (single inheritance).

Comment: @Wim.van.Gool We are talking about other way around. If we give `TType` `B` as input, compiler should be able to infer `Branch, BranchLog`

Comment: @Wim.van.Gool Actually the C# compiler knows exactly which types of A<T,U> will be around at runtime because generic instances are instantiated at compile time in C#. The problem here is that any number of classes besides B can also extend the generic instance A<Branch,BranchLog> so this is asking the compiler to say "if B is the only sub-class of A<Branch,BranchLog> give me an instance of B"? Without some other notation linking B specifically to the Mapper class, the compiler can't decide that on its own, but it has nothing to do with not knowing which instances of A`2 exist.

Comment: @Melvin: generic classes can just as easily be created at runtime using reflection. Moreover, if I use a plug-in architecture I can dynamically add libraries containing more (compile time created) types that are a sub-class of A<,>. So in addition to the problem you mention (to infer type parameters from the types of A<,> it knows of), even if it can see only a single sub-type of A<,>, it still cannot be sure the inferred types of the Get<>-method will be correct at runtime.

Comment: @Wim.van.Gool sure I'm well aware of the possibilities of creating classes at runtime, but that isn't the reason the compiler can't do such inference that is being discussed. Even if you removed the dynamic scenario, the problem is unchanged here.

Comment: @Melvin. I was just referring to your statement that the C#-compiler will know exactly which types of A<> will be around at runtime, which it will not. :) I agree that with or without dynamic types the problem remains, but it does add to the problem of automatic inferring type parameters this way.

Comment: @Sriram: Yep I must say this is obviously the best solution. This may forced me to refactor quite a good number of codes, but at the end I am happy to do the right thing in first place. Thank you

Comment: @DiponRoy Welcome. Am glad that it helped.

Answer (score 1):

> or any way rather than reflection

sure. Old-style `if` statement:

```
public TLog GetMapped<TEntity, TLog>(TEntity entity)
{
    if(typeof(TEntity) == typeof(Branch) && typeof(TLog) == typeof(BranchLog))
    {
        B b = new B();
        return (TLog)b.Get((Branch)entity);
    }
    return default(TLog);
}
```

But that doesn't look like proper usage of generics or inheritance. Are you sure you're not trying to solve an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/208082)?

Comment: @MatthewHaugen You're correct. Also, `null` should probably be `default(TLog)`.

Comment: I agree with the statement, that it seems to be the case of XY problem. Hope the question can be further clarified with actual design problem being solved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that any number of classes besides `B` can also extend the generic instance `A<Branch,BranchLog>` so this is asking the compiler to say "if `B` is the only sub-class of `A<Branch,BranchLog>` give me an instance of `B`"? Without some other notation linking `B` specifically to a specific generic method in the Mapper class, the compiler can't decide that on its own. If you try to accomplish this "automagically" without generics or some other explicit link of `Branch,BranchLog` -> `B` then you are essentially asking the compiler to automate the equivalent of:

```
assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => typeof(B).BaseType == t).FirstOrDefault()
```

This is not really specific to generics. We can rewrite this problem without generics by replacing the `A<Branch,BranchLog>` instance with simple class `A1`.

```
class A {}

class A1 : A {}

class B : A1 {}

class Mapper {
     void Fun(A1) {
         // How to get B b = new B() since I know A1
         // There is no automatic way at compile time, using the type system
     }
}
```

Because nothing keeps me from also declaring:

```
class C : A1 {}
class D : A1 {}
```

Now `B`, `C` and `D` are all instances of `A1`.

I think you need to rethink your class design.

1. If you can't modify the Mapper class, consider some sort of generic factory class or method. You should be able to write a factory method with 3 generic type parameters which would map the particular subclass (`B`) to the particular generic instance arguments used for `A<TEntity,TLog>`.

   `public V GetMapped<T,U,V>(U u) { return new T().Get(U) as V; }`
2. Resort to other mechanisms to decide which class maps to your "signature" as listed in other answers (RTTI / is/as). But it seems to me if you are already using generics, you should stick with a generic solution.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you CAN do it without refelction, but than you need to know all possible types that may be inferred for TEntity and TLOG respectivly.

Try

```
public TLog GetMapped<TEntity, TLog>(TEntity entity)
{
    if(typeof(TEntity) == typeof(Branch) && typeof(TLog) == typeof(BranchLog))
    {
        B b = new B();
        return b.Get(entity);
    }
    return null;
}
```

But you may also override your GetMapped method in derived type B in order to get an instance of this class where you can call `b.Get(entity)`

However, if there are more then this single type (and that´s usually the case on generics, why else you should use them?!), that´s not real good option.

Comment: Did you just copy/paste code from my answer with a little bit of comments before/after?

Answer (score -1):

The funny thing is that by making GetMapped<> generic like that, the client of the Mapper-class already has to know exactly which mapping should be there. Regardless of it's specific implementation, I would rethink what you are trying to do here. Could you be more specific as to what the GetMapped<>-method will be used for in the first place?

EDIT: in an attempt to post an alternative solution, why don't you just put specific instances of your sub-classes into an actual Dictionary inside your Mapper-class:

```
public class Mapper
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> _instances;

    public Mapper()
    {
        _instances = new Dictionary<Type, object>()
        {
            { typeof(Branch), new B() },
            ...
        };
    }

    public TLog GetMapped<TEntity, TLog>(TEntity entity)
    {
        A<TEntity, TLog> a = (A<TEntity, TLog>) _instances[typeof(TEntity)];

        return a.Get(entity);
    }
}
```